# Enzyme Inhibition by alpha-2 macroglobulin

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, enzymes

Alpha-2 macroglobulin is a plasma protein which acts as an anti-protease. It does so by a "bait mechanism" - the protease cleaves the bait domain, following which a conformational change causes binding of alpha2-macroglobulin with the protease, and consequent irreversible inhibition of the protease.

This seems to be very similar to "suicide inhibition" or "mechanism based inhibition" - when an enzyme catalyses a substrate analog's conversion to an active inhibitor, which subsequently binds strongly to the enzyme to inactivate it.

Is alpha2-macroglobulin's inhibition of proteases a case of suicide inhibition then? If it is, why is not more commonly described as that (I have not come across any description of alpha2-macroglobulin as a suicide inhibitor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets first see the proper definition of Suicide Inhibition as given by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_inhibition) (emphasis mine):

> In biochemistry, suicide inhibition, also known as suicide inactivation or mechanism-based inhibition, is an irreversible form of enzyme inhibition that occurs when an enzyme binds $\alpha$ substrate analogue and *forms an irreversible complex with it* through a covalent bond *during the "normal" catalysis reaction*. The inhibitor binds to the active site where it is modified by the enzyme to produce a reactive group that reacts irreversibly to form a stable inhibitor-enzyme complex. This usually uses a prosthetic group or a coenzyme, forming electrophilic alpha and beta unsaturated carbonyl compounds and imines.

Now, lets see how $\alpha$-2-Macroglobulin works, again by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-2-Macroglobulin) (emphasis mine):

> $\alpha$M protease inhibitors *inhibit by steric hindrance*. The mechanism involves protease cleavage of the bait region, a segment of the $\alpha$M that is particularly susceptible to proteolytic cleavage, which initiates a conformational change such that the $\alpha$M collapses about the protease. In the resulting $\alpha$M-protease complex, the *active site of the protease is sterically shielded*, thus substantially decreasing access to protein substrates. Two additional events occur as a consequence of bait region cleavage, namely (i) the h-cysteinyl-g-glutamyl thiol ester becomes highly reactive and (ii) a major conformational change exposes a conserved COOH-terminal receptor binding domain (RBD). RBD exposure allows the $\alpha$M protease complex to bind to clearance receptors and be removed from circulation.

So, clearly, it is not suicide inhibition as:

- $\alpha$M protease inhibitor does not form an irreversible complex with the protease, instead it uses steric hindrance to **prevent protease from binding any substrate**.
- this inhibition does not occur during the "normal" catalysis reaction, it is after the protease has catalyzed a reaction that the inhibitor covers it up, more like the **consequence of catalysis**.
- the inhibitor does not bind to protease active site, it **covers the active site** like a shield.

[image: Putative mechanism of protease entrapment and inhibition by ECAM]
`Putative mechanism of protease entrapment and inhibition by ECAM (Escherichia coli Alpha-2 Macroglobulin)`

*References:*

1. [Suicide Inhibition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_inhibition)
2. [$\alpha$-2 Macroglobulin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-2-Macroglobulin)
3. [Structure of protease-cleaved *Escherichia coli* $\alpha$-2 macroglobulin reveals a putative mechanism of conformational activation for protease entrapment](http://journals.iucr.org/d/issues/2015/07/00/mn5091/mn5091.pdf) (PDF)